# How can I send a message down a websocket running in a thread from tkinter?

Tags: python, asynchronous, tkinter, websocket, coroutine

I have a server script running:

```
async def give_time(websocket,path):
    while True:
        await websocket.send(str(datetime.datetime.now()))
        await asyncio.sleep(3)

start_server = websockets.serve(give_time, '192.168.1.32', 8765)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

which is working fine, just sending the current time every 3 seconds.

I can receive that string from the client which runs this code:

```
async def hello(): #takes whatever text comes through the websocket and displays it in the socket_text label.

    async with websockets.connect('ws://wilsons.lan:8765') as ws:
        while True:
            text = await ws.recv()
            logger.info('message received through websocket:{}'.format(text))
            socket_text.configure(text=text) #socket_text is a tkinter object

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()

def socketstuff():
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(hello())

t = threading.Thread(target=socketstuff,daemon=True)
```

It runs in a thread so that I can run `tkinter.mainloop` in the main thread. This is the *first* time I ever used `threading` so I may be getting it wrong, but it seems to work at present.

What I need to do, is to be able to send a message down the websocket based on a tkinter event - currently just clicking a button next to a text box, but eventually more complex things. The clicking part works fine.

I'm having a lot of trouble with the sending of the message. I've tried a lot of different things, with and without `async` and `await`, although that may have just been panic.

The main problem seems to be that I can't access `ws` from outside that `hello()` function. This makes sense as I'm using the `with` context manager. However, if I just use `ws = websockets.connect('ws://host')` then I get a `websockets.py35.client.Connect object` which wen I try to use the `send` (or indeed `recv`) methods, I get a `object has no attribute 'send'` error.

I hope this is enough info - will happily post anything else required!

Comment: From considering the problem some more, it seems like I've written it wrong here. The threading is not the issue - I've changed it so that `tkinter.mainloop()` runs in the asyncio main loop, so now there is no need for threading. However the problem with accessing the websocket outside the context manager remains. What I'm going to try now is to use an `asyncio.queue` for the tkinter event to add websocket message tasks to, and have an asyncio function that takes them from the queue and does them. Will post an answer if it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the best way of solving this is *not* to use threads.

[This post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/33ecpl/neat_discovery_how_to_combine_asyncio_and_tkinter/) helped me solve it. It shows that you can run, in a coroutine, *one* iteration of the tkinter mainloop:

```
async def do_gui(root,interval=0.05):
    while True:
        root.update()
        await asyncio.sleep(interval)
```

However, the best way of getting a tkinter event to spawn a websocket message is to use `asyncio.queue`. Making the tkinter callback add an item to the queue using `put_nowait()` and having a coroutine which runs at the same time as `do_gui` which uses `await queue.get()` to get the message from the queue works for me.